# Submitting more than one html tag cause 404 Error in Codeigniter and Grocery Crud?

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm using grocery crud with codeigniter to change some database columns,but I have a problem when I use html tags, I get 404 Not found error in firebug.

The following work:
[image]

But the following doesn't work because I have tried to style it :
[image]

When I click on source in the top left of the WYSIWYG editor and try to type in my html, sometimes it works and sometimes not:

```
<p>This works</p>
```

The following doesn't work (404 Not found):

```
<p> This <p>Hello</p> Not work </p>
```

The following doesn't work (404 Not found ):
    `<p></p>`

The following works
    `<p>aaaa</p>`

Any idea why do I get 404 if the I put an empty

tag but it works if I put something inside ?? Thanks in advance
As long as I can see, it only works with 1 tag but if I use more than one tag it doesn't work :

```
<h1> This single line work </h1>
```

But if I use more than 1 html tag it won't work, for example the following doesn't work ( 404 Not found ?)

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>World</h1>
```

Comment: It seems you getting error at your php code.When you save with blank I think it does not get any value but your code may be trying to do something.check and find at your controller where the error or you can add the code with the question.

Comment: provide your PHP code

Comment: Show the URL that is posted to when the post succeeds

Answer (score 0):

Though there is very little information given, have you inserted the html tags inside the visual mode of the editor or html mode ? try inserting in html mode and paste. I think the issue at your end is related to special characters.