# codeigniter allow "http://" in get variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

My app is based on Codeigniter Framework

If I type the following url, I get 404 error :

http://example.com/mycontroller/func/?url=http://www.hello.com

but if type anything other that http  it work normally, for example

http://example.com/mycontroller/func/?url=ptth://www.hello.com

*EDIT:*
I want to achieve this because I have a form that doesn't submit when I use the word http inside it, this form need to be stored into the database. I don't know why this happen at all but all I know is that if I can get the  app to work the url form above it would probably work fix my problem with the form too as long as the problem looks similar  [Here's my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396975/submitting-more-than-one-html-tag-cause-404-error-in-codeigniter-and-grocery-cru)

Why codeigniter doesn't allow the word http:// to be passed as a get variable and How can enable the word 'http://' to be able to pass through the URL ?

Comment: what do you mean it does not work?

Comment: In config.php, what do you have for: `$config['enable_query_strings']` ?

Comment: I tried to set it to true but no luck @CodeGodie

Comment: @CodeGodie : That variable is `false` in my project. But, it still works with URL in query.

Comment: `Why codeigniter doesn't allow the word http:// `? its allow. try to printout `$this->input->get('url')` you will see what you receive

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your config file has the following:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = true;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-=&?';
```

Note the `?` added to `permitted_uri_chars`