# how to allow http:// as value of a GET variable after controller segment?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can someone please tell me why the following gives an error 404

```
 http://example.com/welcome/?=http://
```

but any thing else work normally, eg:

```
 http://example.com/welcome/?=hppt://
 http://example.com/welcome/?=htpp://
 http://example.com/welcome/?=pthh://
```

And this also works :

```
 http://example.com/welcome/?=http:/ ( with single slash)
```

Please help, I'm running into serious trouble and I'm going to reinvent more than 1 month of work just because of this mistake...

Comment: You have asked the [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398913/codeigniter-allow-http-in-get-variable) twice in span of just 3hrs. you need to use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) as mentioned by Jonathan.

Answer (score 3):

Try encoding your query string like this

http://example.com/welcome/?=http:%2F%2F

Comment: Also, in php you can build your query string using `http_build_query($array)` with an array, you can pass any of the values through `urlencode($string)` or in javascript you can use `encodeURIComponent(str)` on any of the values to get the right encoding.